# How to make a calculation according to the month (each month correponds a value) inserted in a textfield ios - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a textfield where the user inserts a specific month with a pickerview. Every month has to correspond to a certain number (which are the working hours in that month).

I need the number for a calculation

here is the code that I wrote:

```
let redditonetto = Float(reddito.text!) ?? 0
let totaleore = Float(ore.text!) ?? 0


//da reddito 0 a 1247.73
let calcA = redditonetto / 168;
let calcB = totaleore * calcA;
let calcC = calcB * 0.80;
let calcD = calcC - (calcC * 0.0584)
let trat = calcC * 0.0584
```

If you see *let calcA*, I need that *redditonetto* will be divided to a number according to the month inserted in the textfield.

Comment: `?? "0"` Is pointless. The text property will never return nil. UITextField text property default value is an empty string. Just force unwrap it `ore.text!`

Comment: The code is right.. the problem is in let calcA where redditonetto has to be divided to a number according to the text in a textfield (which is called mese) that the user takes from a pickerview. Thanks a lot

Comment: I mean ?? “0” will never be executed

Comment: so which modification I need to do? Thank

Comment: i do not understand what you really want and what you want to calculate...maybe you should be more precise....

Comment: The costant let calcA makes a calculation dividing redditonetto with 168. But 168 is a test number. I want a division by redditonetto with a number according to the month inserted in a textfield

Comment: example : user insert JANUARY and I want to tie january to a number (ex. 10)

Comment: so when the user insert January, tha app will divide redditonetto with 10

Comment: @aker10 Can you show some example inputs and outputs? How is the user choosing a Month? What are the numbers for each month? Are they stored in a Dictionary, Array or something else?

Comment: @DanielT. The user choose a month in a textfield with a pickerview. The number of the month are in an array  here it is: let oremese:[String:Int] = ["Gennaio": 184, "Febbraio": 160, "Marzo": 176, "Aprile": 176, "Maggio": 168, "Giugno": 176, "Luglio": 184, "Agosto": 168, "Settembre": 176, "Ottobre": 176, "Novembre": 168, "Dicembre": 184]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```swift
func trat(income: UITextField, hours: UITextField, picker: UIPickerView, monthHours: [Float]) -> Float {
    let netIncome = Float(income.text!) ?? 0
    let totalHours = Float(hours.text!) ?? 0
    let month = picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    guard 0 <= month && month < 12 else { return 0 }

    //income 0 to 1247.73
    let calcA = netIncome / monthHours[month];
    let calcB = totalHours * calcA;
    let calcC = calcB * 0.80;
    let calcD = calcC - (calcC * 0.0584)
    return calcD
}
```

However, note that this won't work (will return 0) unless a month has been selected.

Answer (score 0):

thank you Daniel T. I really appreciate. I give you my code to understand How to implement and when put return

```
@IBAction func calcolaPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {


        let oremese = ["Gennaio": 184, "Febbraio": 160, "Marzo": 176, "Aprile": 176, "Maggio": 168, "Giugno": 176, "Luglio": 184, "Agosto": 168, "Settembre": 176, "Ottobre": 176, "Novembre": 168, "Dicembre": 184]


        func trat(income: UITextField, hours: UITextField, picker: UIPickerView, oremese: [Float]) -> Float {
        let redditonetto = Float(reddito.text!) ?? 0
        let totaleore = Float(ore.text!) ?? 0
        let month = picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        guard 0 <= month && month < 12 else { return 0 }



        //da reddito 0 a 1247.73
        let calcA = redditonetto / 168;
        let calcB = totaleore * calcA;
        let calcC = calcB * 0.80;
        let calcD = calcC - (calcC * 0.0584)
        let trat = calcC * 0.0584


        let myDoubleC = calcC
        let doubleStrC = (String(format: "%.2f", myDoubleC))

        let myDoubleD = calcD
        let doubleStrD = (String(format: "%.2f", myDoubleD))

        let myDoubleT = trat
        let doubleStrT = (String(format: "%.2f", myDoubleT))



        //da reddito 1247.74 a 2159.49
        let calcB2 = totaleore * 5.67;
        let calcC2 = calcB2 - (calcB2 * 0.0584)
        let trat2 = calcC2 * 0.0584

        let myDoubleB2 = calcB2
        let doubleStrB2 = (String(format: "%.2f", myDoubleB2))

        let myDoubleC2 = calcC2
        let doubleStrC2 = (String(format: "%.2f", myDoubleC2))

        let myDoubleT2 = trat2
        let doubleStrT2 = (String(format: "%.2f", myDoubleT2))



        //da reddito da 2159.50 a 30000
        let calcB3 = totaleore * 7.14;
        let calcC3 = calcB3 - (calcB3 * 0.0584)
        let trat3 = calcC3 * 0.0584

        let myDoubleB3 = calcB3
        let doubleStrB3 = (String(format: "%.2f", myDoubleB3))

        let myDoubleC3 = calcC3
        let doubleStrC3 = (String(format: "%.2f", myDoubleC3))

        let myDoubleT3 = trat3
        let doubleStrT3 = (String(format: "%.2f", myDoubleT3))


        if redditonetto >= 0 && redditonetto <= 1247.73 {
                nettocig.text = "€ " + "\(doubleStrD)"
                indennitalorda.text = "€ " + "\(doubleStrC)"
                trattenute.text = "€ " + "\(doubleStrT)"
            }
        else if redditonetto >= 1247.74 && redditonetto <= 2159.49 {
                nettocig.text = "€ " + "\(doubleStrC2)"
                indennitalorda.text = "€ " + "\(doubleStrB2)"
                trattenute.text = "€ " + "\(doubleStrT2)"
        } else {
                nettocig.text = "€ " + "\(doubleStrC3)"
                indennitalorda.text = "€ " + "\(doubleStrB3)"
                trattenute.text = "€ " + "\(doubleStrT3)"
        }



        if redditonetto >= 0 && redditonetto <= 2159.49{
            massimale.text = "€ 998.18"
            progressBar.progress = 0.7
        }
        else { massimale.text = "€ 1199.72"
            progressBar.progress = 1
    }

    }




}
}
```